# Can I use a custom build logger side by side with the standard logger?

Tags: c#, logging, msbuild

I have a custom build logger based on the BasicFileLogger example at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171471%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It's working nicely, but if I want to use it on the build server, I need its output to be in addition to what's already output with the default logger, but written to a separate file (and with different options). To make matters slightly more interesting, the existing build logging scheme creates a new file each time, but I want mine to append to a file. (If it matters, we build several projects on the command line via separate invocations of msbuild.exe rather than using a master solution file).

One approach I'm looking at is encapsulating a class that implements the default logger behavior with mine, which will get the first crack at the warning and error events so I can write them out to my file in my format, but then forward them to the inner class to write them out to the file specified with /filelogger. The first question is, is this necessary? If so, can I pass two different log file names on the command line, or would one of them need to be set "magically" (e.g. with an environment variable) and the other passed with /filelogger. I think this is the general approach used in this [article](http://www.wintellect.com/blogs/jrobbins/smarter-logging-with-msbuild).

Answer (score 1):

Certainly!

Check out the command line switches [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx).  Note the "Append" switch to enable the requested behavior.

I see that link provides this sample to control the console output with the custom logger:

```
MSBuild /nologo /noconsolelogger /logger:SimpleLogger.dll /verbosity:Detailed
```

You can have various loggers running using /cl to manage the console logger and /flN for the various file loggers.

```
msbuild.exe /fl1 /flp1:Verbosity=diag;logfile=msbuild.log;append;
```

Comment: Thank you.

That's close to what we've got now I thnk. The problem I have is that the existing process uses /filelogger to capture the default output, plus redirects console output to another file (which I didn't mention above). My new logger would need to be called with /logger with a different output file name than the one passed into /filelogger.

So can one of my file loggers be the one passed into the new custom logger dll? If so, do I need to worry about the other loggers not getting a crack at the events I want to handle?